# Why are duplicate email addresses being skipped?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA code that populates information in an Outlook e-mail template based on each populated row.  In those rows are email addresses that are held as strings.

When the code runs into a duplicate email address it will only send one e-mail (usually the first one in the list). What can I modify to ensure it sends an e-mail for every cell that has an email address?

```vb
'**********You MUST DO THIS FIRST**********
'On the Tools menu, click References.
'In the Available References list, 
' click to select the 'Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library check box. Click OK.

'--- Set up the Outlook objects.
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment
Dim body As String
Dim T As Integer
Dim Y As Integer

'--- Declare our global variables to be used in each subroutine.
Dim CustomerAddress As String
Dim CustomerMessage As String


Sub dayonemail()
'--- Declare our variables.
Dim X As Integer
Dim AA As Long, i As Long
Sheets(4).Select
Range("A1").Select

AA = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If AA >= 3 Then

'--- Sets which row to start searching for e-mail addresses and names.
X = 2

'--- Begin looping through all the e-mail addresses in column A until
'    a blank cell is hit.
While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X).Text <> ""
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
'--- These variables will be used to search for duplicates.
'    CustomerAddress = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("J" & X).Text
    TempCustomerAddress = CustomerAddress

    '--- Increment X until a different e-mail address is found.
    While TempCustomerAddress = CustomerAddress
        X = X + 1
        CustomerAddress = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X).Text
    Wend
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------
    '--- Add the e-mail address to a global variable.
    CustomerAddress = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X - 1).Text
    '--- Run the subroutine to send the message.


    '--- This is required to prevent a name which does not resolve to
    '    an e-mail address from hanging the app.
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Create the Outlook session.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Create the message.
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\me\new.oft")

    F = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("B" & X - 1)
    G = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("E" & X - 1)
    H = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("Z" & X - 1)
    J = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("Z" & X - 1)
    k = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("F" & X - 1)
    l = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("G" & X - 1)
    M = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("H" & X - 1)
    n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I" & X - 1)
    o = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("J" & X - 1)

    With objOutlookMsg
        ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(CustomerAddress)
        objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field1", F)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field2", G)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field3", H)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field4", J)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field5", k)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field6", l)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field7", M)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field8", n)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field9", o)
        '.Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance

       ' Add attachments to the message.
        If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
            Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath)
        End If

        ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
        For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
            objOutlookRecip.Resolve
            If Not objOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
            Resume Next
        End If
        Next
        .Send '--- Send the message.

    End With

    '--- Remove the message and Outlook application from memory.
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

Wend
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any logic here that would cause a duplicate to not get emailed. Perhaps remove that "On ERror Resume Next" and see if that suppressing something?

Comment: I'm lost, I went ahead and  removed that "On ERror Resume Next" and everything still went through as normal.  No scripting errors to be found.

Comment: Reading through this script again... I'm assuming that the duplicates are always next to each other? I see the duplicate detection code and it looks like it runs down the rows until it finds a non-duplicate, then continues. Are they always adjacent?

Comment: Currently they are alternating.  It is 3 of one e-mail and 3 of another.  1 of ted's goes through and all 3 of bob's go through.  Bob is fine, but ted is only getting one of them!  It's the oddest thing.

Comment: Oh yea... that is weird. This code is a little strange too. I'll noodle on it.

Comment: Would very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick rewrite that just moves row by row sending an email for every email on the row. I've dispensed with the While loop and replaced it with a For loop that loops for each row, as a range. It seems, to me at least, a little more clear what is happening in the code.

```
'**********You MUST DO THIS FIRST**********'On the Tools menu, click References.
'In the Available References list, click to select the 'Microsoft Outlook 9.0 Object Library check box. Click OK.
'--- Set up the Outlook objects.
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment
Dim body As String


'--- Declare our global variables to be used in each subroutine.
Dim CustomerAddress As String
Dim CustomerMessage As String


Sub dayonemail()
    '--- Declare our variables.
    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim readRow as Range
    Dim CountOfRows As Long

    '---determine how many rows of data we have
    CountOfRows = Sheets("day1").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '--- Only continue if we have more than 2 rows. 
    If CountOfRows > 2 Then

        '--- Create the outlook session outside the loop
        Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        '--- Loop through all populated rows, starting at row 2 to the last row sending emails as we go
        For each readRow in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("day1").Range("I2:I" & CountOfRows).Rows

            '--- email address (Column I or column number 9)
            CustomerAddress = readRow.Cells(1, 9).Value

            '--- Get email body parts
            F = readRow.Cells(1, 2).value
            G = readRow.Cells(1, 5).value 
            H = readRow.Cells(1, 26).value 
            J = readRow.Cells(1, 26).value 
            k = readRow.Cells(1, 6).value  
            l = readRow.Cells(1, 7).value
            M = readRow.Cells(1, 8).value  
            n = readRow.Cells(1, 9).value  
            o = readRow.Cells(1, 10).value  

            '--- Create the message.
            Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\me\new.oft")            

            With objOutlookMsg
                '--- Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
                Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(CustomerAddress)
                objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field1", F)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field2", G)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field3", H)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field4", J)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field5", k)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field6", l)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field7", M)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field8", n)
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Field9", o)
                '.Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance

               '--- Add attachments to the message.
                If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
                    Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath)
                End If

                '--- Resolve each Recipient's name.
                For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
                    objOutlookRecip.Resolve
                    If Not objOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
                    Resume Next
                End If
                Next
                .Send '--- Send the message.

            End With

            '--- Remove the message from memory
            Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing


        Next readRow

        '--- Get rid of the outlook application
        Set objOutlook = Nothing    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this.  The current code here is erroring out first at the attachment section, then at the recipient check.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm glad you got it up and running! I got slammed with meetings yesterday afternoon so I couldn't jump in and troubleshoot.